# How do I ignore stdin with `xargs`?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, xargs

I'm using `xargs` + `seq` to run a command several thousand times in parrallel.

e.g. running `curl` 10,000 times with 20 parrallel processes:

```
seq 1 10000 | xargs -n1 -P20 curl "https://www.example.com/foo"
```

However `xargs` is appending the output of `stdin` to the command it runs (which is what it's designed to do by default). So it ends up effectively running:

```
curl "https://www.example.com/foo" 1
curl "https://www.example.com/foo" 2
curl "https://www.example.com/foo" 3
curl "https://www.example.com/foo" 4
...
```

which causes my `curl` command to error out.

How can I have `xargs` "ignore" the `stdin` value here and just output a null/empty value?

I tried a `for` loop instead but that doesn't run the statements in parallel, which I require.

I also tried formatting the `seq` as empty strings (`seq -f'' 1 10000`) which outputs 10,000 blank lines correctly, but `xargs` ignores this blank input and never runs any commands.

Thanks!

Comment: You will find both xargs and parallel alone answers there, and more.

Comment: Use the for loop and add an `&` to the end of each command to fork them into the background. i.e. `curl "https://www.example.com/foo" &`

Comment: It's not just a default.  Running commands with **arg**uments drawn from the standard input is the whole point of `xargs`.  For suitably formed inputs it is possible to work around that (via the `-I` option), but that has bad code smell.

Comment: Thanks! I see your point but I'd argue that the point of `xargs` is to run commands based on the _presence_ of inputs. How that input ends up being used is not a concern. But appreciate you pointing me to the `-I` flag! That's helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `xargs -I {}` you can place the stdin with another `{}` where you want. If you do not position it in the command the stdin is ignored.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I ended up running: `seq 1 10000 | xargs -n1 -P20 -I {} curl "https://www.example.com/foo"` and I see that it runs 20 processes in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off running the following. This will only redirect the web address back into xargs 1000 times.

```
for i in $(seq 1000)
  do echo "https://www.example.com/foo" | xargs -n1 -P20 curl
done
```

or as a one-liner:

```
for i in $(seq 1000);do echo "https://www.example.com/foo" | xargs -n1 -P20 curl;done
```

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't this just run it sequentially 1,000 times instead of in parallel? The `-P20` has no effect since it only receives one `stdin` each iteration of the loop. I tried it out with `seq 5` and `-P20` and overall the `curl` ran only 5 times, sequentially